# Copy elastic beanstalk configuration to an environment in another region

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I have setup an elastic beanstalk application and environment using the AWS Web Console. Now I need to copy the configuration of this environment to another one in a different region.
Is there any way to do that.
Can anybody help me with a detailed documentation for that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy one elastic beanstalk environment configuration from a region to another in the following way.

I  - Save an environment's configuration

```
1. Open the Elastic Beanstalk console
2. Navigate to the management page for your environment.
3. Choose Actions, and then choose Save Configuration.
4. Use the on-screen form to name the saved configuration. Optionally, provide a brief description, and add tag keys and values.
5. Choose Save.
```

II  - Initialise the EB CLI with the environment in first region

III - Download saved configuration

```
1. You can download a configuration using the EB CLI eb config command, as shown in the following example.
        `eb config get NAME`        ; where NAME is the name of your saved configuration.
```

IV - Initialise the EB CLI with the environment in second region

V  - Upload configuration file to elastic bean stalk environment in another region

```
1. You can upload a configuration file using following command.
        `eb config put filename`    ; where `filename` is the name of configuration file without the full path. 
                                        The filename must have the file extension .cfg.yml
    (Now you can see the configuration in `Saved configuration` in the second environment )
```

VI - Apply a saved configuration during environment creation (Elastic Beanstalk console)

```
1. Open the Elastic Beanstalk console.
2. Choose an application.
3. Choose Saved Configurations.
4. Choose a saved configuration, and then choose Launch environment.
5. Proceed through the wizard to create your environment.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I get an error "ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError -" when I try to upload my config. I tried using just the filename, relative path, absolute path but none of them worked. Do you have any ideas?